# I have some problem with loop and argument when reversing

Tags: c, reverse-engineering

First is about the variable I got when reverse     `sub_804851C((int)aThepasswordise, &s1);` .Basically the function compare a value with input but the problem is value of        `aThepasswordise` is a string like `HeyIAmNoob` so what is the value of     `(int)aThepasswordise` ?

Second I got a loop like this

```
for ( result = *(unsigned __int8 *)a1; (_BYTE)result; result = (unsigned __int8)*v2 )
```

I dont understand what is the last value and the jump of this loop? 
Thankyou so much and sorry because my English is bad

Comment: It looks like an absolutely ghastly micro-optimisation to me, that's possibly undefined. Have a sympathetic upvote.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About the first question.

Strings in C are `char` sequences ending with `\0`.
`aThepasswordise` is probably a pointer to such sequence so casting it to `int` will give you the value of the pointer as an `int`

In the loop, you start by taking the first byte to which `a1` is pointing to.
Then the `result` var is compared if it is `0` and at each iteration, `result` is changed to the first byte of `v2`.

The jump will be determined by the change of where `v2` is pointing and how is it changed at each iteration.

Comment: so in fmy first question the value will be the offset address of the string right ?

Comment: @DŨNGĐỖ Well if the string is defined as `char* aThepasswordise = "Some Str";` then `(int) aThepasswordise` will give you the address as an `int`. Generally, the addresses are integers with the size of the processor word.
So you should get this value.